# Python/Django 'Type object is not iterable' Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to GET fetch my REST API in DRF, but keep getting the error below.
What could be the problem?
Thanks!

```
Internal Server Error: /polls/
.....
.....
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
[08/Aug/2021 07:02:50] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 500 100344
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/Aug/2021 07:02:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3415
```

The apiviews code: apiviews.py

```
class PollList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Poll.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PollSerializer
```

The polls code: models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serializer.py:

```
class PollSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", PollList.as_view(), name="polls_list"),
]
```

Admin URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^', include('vote.urls')),
]
```

Here's portions of the traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /polls/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Studio\Python\REST\elections\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner 
....
....
\rest_framework\views.py", line 400, in initial        
    self.check_permissions(request)
  File "D:\Studio\Python\REST\elections\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 332, in check_permissions
    for permission in self.get_permissions():
  File "D:\Studio\Python\REST\elections\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 279, in get_permissions    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Here's the Settings.py code implementing the Authentication:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    )
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ....
    ....
]
```

Comment: Please share the serializer and url as well.

Comment: I've updated above. Added the urls.py and serializer.py.

Comment: please share full stack strace

Comment: I've added portions of the traceback and admin URLs.

Comment: Do you have default permissions in your settings.py?

Comment: I'm using DRF Authentication as shown in the settings code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing comma in the `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` tuple, which effectively makes it not a tuple, but a single scalar value.

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', # !!!!
)
```

Comment: WOOOOOW!!! YOU'RE THE BEST. WORKS LIKE MAGIC. THANKS ALOTTTTT!!!